# Subquery to obtain last record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: `User` and `Session`. For each User, I would like know if the last record in session table was created last year.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT MAX(`Session`.acDateF) as MaxDateF
    FROM `Session`
    WHERE `Session`.acType='1'
) as AcDate
GROUP BY `Session`.userId) 
WHERE YEAR(`Session`.acDateF) =YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())-1
```

If the User has a record in the `Session` table this year it doesn't appear in the result.

Comment: Do you want "as AcDate" to come after your Group By statement?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear, but it sounds like you want something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Session` s
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(`Session`.acDateF) as MaxDateF, `Session`.userId
    FROM `Session`
    WHERE `Session`.acType='1'
        AND YEAR(s.acDateF) =YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())-1
    GROUP `Session`.userId
) as AcDate
    ON s.userId = AcDate.userId
    AND s.acDateF = AcDate.MaxDateF;
```

Or if you want the user data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `user` u
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(`Session`.acDateF) as MaxDateF, `Session`.userId
    FROM `Session`
    WHERE `Session`.acType='1'
        AND YEAR(s.acDateF) =YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())-1
    GROUP `Session`.userId
) as AcDate
    ON u.userId = AcDate.userId;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    MAX(`Session`.acDateF) as MaxDateF,
    `Session`.userId
FROM `Session`
WHERE `Session`.acType='1'
GROUP BY `Session`.userId
having MAX(YEAR(`Session`.acDateF)) as MaxDateF =YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way.  It uses a correlated subquery in the `where` clause to get the last date for the previous year:

```
select *
from session s
where s.acDatef = (select MAX(se.acDatef)
                   from session s2
                   where s2.userid = s.userid and
                         YEAR(`Session`.acDateF) =YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())-1
                  )
```